# Как в JSON файле обновлять информацию при запросе

Tags: php, javascript, json

Можно ли в `JSON` файле обновлять информацию при запросе к нему(например запрос к `file.json`)? Исполняется ли какой-нибудь код в таком файле? Или какие еще есть способы обновлять этот файл при запросе?

Comment: Только если это серверный скрипт, который выдает ответ JSON. Сам по себе JSON файл не будет исполнятся на сервере, только если не настроить это для сервера через расширение или в правилах в .htaccess

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, а как это можно было бы настроить через .htaccess?